# Как изменить название загружаемого файла в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Пробую так:

```
$typefile =$request->file('filename')->getMimeType();
$fileName = $uid.'|'.$variant.'|'.$subject.'.'.$typefile;
$request->file('filename')->move('upload/', $fileName)
```

В папку загружается файл, имя которого есть тип этого файла. А при загрузке выясняется, что, к примеру, картинка и вовсе стала исполняемым файлом с расширением exe.

К примеру:

Отправляю картинку с расширением png.

Делаю:

```
 echo $fileName;
```

Получаю:

```
228869386|3|inf.image/png
```

А в папке:

Название: png, тип: exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Laravel можно обращаться к динамическому свойству класса созвучному с именем ид из запроса

```
$request->file('filename')
```

Можно обратиться к методам

```
$full_path_w_ext = $request->filename->path();
$just_ext = $request->filename->extension();
```

Для сохранения достаточно

```
$request->filename->move('upload/', $request->filename->getBasename())
```